# Simple Python question with dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

The goal of the function is to make a grade adjustment based off of a dictionary and list. For instance

```
def adjust_grades(roster, grade_adjustment) 

adjust_grades({'ann': 75, 'bob': 80}, [5, -5])
```

will return

```
{'ann': 80, 'bob': 75}
```

I just need a nudge in the right direction, I'm new to Python so I thought to put a nested for loop for each num in grade_adjustment but its not the right way.

Comment: You should try defining your dictionary as an `OrderedDict`. Or define your `grade_adjustment` as a dictionary: `{'ann' : 5, 'bob' : -5 } `

Comment: @J.Murray, That was true till 3.6. In 3.6 order preserving feature was considered implementation detail. In 3.7+ order-preserving feature is guaranteed

Comment: The `grade_adjustment` should also be a dictionary.  Then, `for name, adj in grade_adjustment.items(): roster[name] += adj`

Comment: @Buran Nice!  Its a solid edition.  I think that I'd still consider alternatives than rely on that (esp if you don't know what version of the interpreter the code may be executed via)

Comment: @Alexander That makes a lot of sense, unfortunately its a solution I cannot use for this assignment. It HAS to be a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Python 3.7 (ordered dicts) and the length of the adjustments match the length of the items in the dictionary, you can [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) them together as follows:

```
for name, adjustment_amount in zip(roster, grade_adjustment):
    roster[name] += adjustment_amount

>>> roster
{'ann': 80, 'bob': 75}
```

Comment: Very simple and easy to follow solution -- thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is making several assumptions:

- the dictionary and the list have the same length (your final code should make sure they do)
- you are using a version of python in which the order of the dictionary keys is preserved (if not, you can make `grade_adjustment` a dictionary as well, as mentioned by other comments)

```
result = roster.copy()
for index, key in enumerate(roster):
    result[key] += grade_adjustment[index]
```

Comment: Ah! Very helpful, that makes a lot of sense. I will try this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
def adjust_grades(roster, grade_adjustment):
    for k, v in enumerate(grade_adjustment):
        roster[list(roster.keys())[k]] = roster[list(roster.keys())[k]] + v
    return roster
```

This gives output as you said `{'ann': 80, 'bob': 75}`

Comment: I will try this too, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

assuming 3.7 or ordered dict and equal length:

```
def adjust_grades(roster, grade_adjustment):
    return {key:value + adjustment for (key, value), adjustment in
            zip(roster.items(), grade_adjustment)}


print(adjust_grades({'ann': 75, 'bob': 80}, [5, -5]))
```